# Opening ContextMenu by Clicking a Button in Android

Tags: android

How to open the ContextMenu in Android by Clicking a Button?

Answer (score 1):

A context menu is conceptually similar to the menu displayed when the user performs a "right-click" on a PC. You should use a context menu to provide the user access to actions that pertain to a specific item in the user interface.

**On Android, a context menu is displayed when the user performs a "long press" (press and hold) on an item.**

Alternatively, if you need a button, you can implement the menu for the view and change the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bad and you should feel bad, given how readily available (if cryptic) the method behind this process is. This small tutorial helped me greatly.

http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/